# Selenium webdrive cannot locate certain classes

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

**Scraping Website**: [cbc](https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/new-brunswick/dieppe-newfoundland-mail-packages-1.5367640)

**Background Info**:

- Chrome webdrive
- python3
- current most up to date version of chrome drive and selenium (11/22/2019).

**My goal**:

> **extract comments from each vf-comment-thread class.**

The **partial structure of html** looks like this:

```
<div class="vf-commenting vf-comments-widget">
...
    <div class="vf-horizontal-list vf3-conversations-list vf3-conversations-list--comments">
        <div class="vf-comment-thread"> ... </div>
        <div class="vf-comment-thread"> ... </div>
        <div class="vf-comment-thread"> ... </div>
        ...
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

**Problem**: When I use selenium to locate to class
`"vf-horizontal-list vf3-conversations-list vf3-conversations-list--comments"`
and store it in a variable: "comm", then print `[i.get_attribute("class") for i in comm.find_elements_by_css_selector("*")]`. It's suppose to show me a list like `[..., "vf-comment-thread", "vf-comment-thread" , "vf-comment-thread", ...]` However, I got empty list.

My **exact commands**:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 14)
comm = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "vf-commenting")))
wait = WebDriverWait(comm, 14)
comms = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//div[@class = 'vf-horizontal-list']")))
print([i.get_attribute("class") for i in comms.find_elements_by_css_selector("*")])
Output: []
```

Comment: ".//div[@class = vvf-horizontal-list']" is missing a quotation mark ("v" where quote should be?)... and you might want contains instead of equals?

Comment: Oh yes, I just didn't copy them over carefully enough. My original code is correct. Thank you for answering tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are facing is that the comments are being dynamically generated by javascript so you will need to scroll down to load them first

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
#Open Browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

def ScrollDown(interal=3.5,looper=20):
    scroll_delay = interal
    count = 0

    ''' Get scroll height'''

    last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

    while count < looper:
        print('Scrolling down to bottom loop {}/{}'.format(count+1,looper))
        ''' Scroll down to bottom'''
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

        ''' Wait to load page'''
        print('sleeping {} secs'.format(interal))
        sleep(scroll_delay)

        ''' Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height'''
        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

        if new_height == last_height:
            break

        last_height = new_height
        count += 1

driver.get('https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/new-brunswick/dieppe-newfoundland-mail-packages-1.5367640')

# this will scroll down the page till all the dynamic content is loaded
ScrollDown()

#Method 1 get all children using * 
childer_xpath = "//div[contains(@class, 'vf-horizontal-list') and contains(@class ,'conversations-list--comments')]/*"
all_children = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(childer_xpath)
if all_children:
    print([i.get_attribute("class") for i in all_children])
#Method 2 get all children using children tag name 
alt_childer_xpath = "//div[contains(@class, 'vf-horizontal-list') and contains(@class ,'conversations-list--comments')]/div"
comm = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(alt_childer_xpath)
if comm:
    print([i.get_attribute("class") for i in comm])
#Method 3 get all children using xpath of the parent then loop throuth it's children
Parent_Cooments_xpath = "//div[contains(@class, 'vf-horizontal-list') and contains(@class ,'conversations-list--comments')]"
parent_tag = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(Parent_Cooments_xpath)
if parent_tag:
    print([i.get_attribute("class") for i in parent_tag[0].find_elements_by_xpath('./*')])
    print([i.get_attribute("class") for i in parent_tag[0].find_elements_by_xpath('*')])
```

**Output :**

```
['vf-comment-thread', 'vf-comment-thread', 'vf-comment-thread']
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for answering my urgent question. I have tried your suggestion, and it still gives me an empty list instead of the set of sub-classes within this div. Do you know another solution or someone who might be an expert at this who can solve my issue? Thank you very much :)

Comment: @sherryyuan I Took a closer look and fixed the issue . you can try it now .

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been stucked on it for so long and you helped me to solve it in just a few hours. Thank you so much again!

Comment: @sherryyuan you are welcome . if you see it useful vote it up .